# How did mosquitoes expand their habitations to a place they never lived before?

Tags: mosquitoes

So, in the region I live, we have some sort of like a "mosquito zone", spanning for thousands of Kilometres, this is the place where you will normally find lots of mosquitoes, and this has been so for years and years. But last year, we were surprised to see that the mosquitoes have "invaded"a village which has never experienced them even once. The village though, is at the border with what I call "mosquito zone" but never has these insects "visited" this village. So I became curious to know, what has happened so that the mosquitoes said "now let's invade this village and live there"? I can't see anything suspicious that has changed. Do we have any explanations?

Answer (score 2):

It could be a number of things. Mosquitos need standing water. Look for that. Any changes? Was last year particularly rainy?  One group of mosquitos lays its eggs at the waters edge. They lie dormant until the water reaches them again. If the water was high when the eggs were laid, then recedes, it may be years before the water reaches them again and the eggs hatch, resulting in a bloom of high numbers. Also, other mosquitos breed in containers. Things like tires, or coffee cans, or flower pots in cemeteries. Even a small amount of stagnant water in a container can result in mosquitos. Any changes there? The obvious change is the warming climate, but I would look first to changes in the water.